# Convert a polygon to a line using SQL Server spatial tools

Tags: sql-server, line, polygon, spatial

I am trying to manipulate a spatial dataset (shapefile) using SQL Server Management Studio v18.

The dataset contains California counties, and I have been able to dissolve all into one polygon using `UnionAggregate(geometrycolumn)`.

What I have not been able to figure out is how to convert the polygon into a line.

I've been trying `STExteriorRing()` and `STBoundary()` but I get a null output when I run it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample data, expected results?

Comment: Does STRingN(1) work?